# How to validate either value or another value in every array items in body?

Tags: java, rest-assured, hamcrest

I am validating response body by checking if in every items name or panCode contains "PAN".

That's doesn't work for validating if every items name or panCode contains "PAN" and i have the error

Expected: every item is (hasProperty("name", a string containing "PAN") or hasProperty("panCode", a string containing "PAN"))

Actual: [{"id":1000000002099,"name":"","panCode":"PANPL00002101","idAttachedDu":1000000008574},{"id":1000000002100,"name":"","panCode":"PANPL00002102","idAttachedDu":1000000008574}]

```
response.then().assertThat().body(everyItem(
                either(hasProperty("name", containsString(criteria)))
               .or(hasProperty("panCode", containsString(criteria)))));
```

How can I validate either name or panCode in body using hamcrest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your example is not working is that `hasProperty(java.lang.String propertyName, Matcher<?> valueMatcher)` matcher is working with JavaBean objects, while JsonPath represents everything as a Map. Take a look at this method's description from Hamcrest's Matchers JavaDoc:

> Creates a matcher that matches when the examined object has a JavaBean
>   property with the specified name whose value satisfies the specified
>   matcher.

When you're working with response using `body(Matcher<?> matcher, Matcher<?>... additionalMatchers)` it converts response JSON to map and JavaBean matcher cannot be applied here. Instead try using matchers that work with `java.util.Map`.

Here's how your example can work:

```
response.then().assertThat()
    .body("$", everyItem(either(hasEntry(equalTo("name"), containsString(criteria)))
        .or(hasEntry(equalTo("panCode"), containsString(criteria)))));
```

Comment: Thanks @bhusak for your answer but it doesn't work `Response body doesn't match expectation.
Expected: every item is (map containing ["name"->a string containing "PAN"] or map containing ["panCode"->a string containing "PAN"])
  Actual: [{"id":1000000002099,"name":"","panCode":"PANPL00002101","idAttachedDu":1000000008574},{"id":1000000002100,"name":"","panCode":"PANPL00002102","idAttachedDu":1000000008574},{"id":1000000001341,"name":"","panCode":"PANPL00001344","idAttachedDu":1000000004962}]`

Comment: Hey @Gabistic! Just fixed that by adding path in body. Try it now

Answer (score 2):

Since response body is straight forward json array, following approach would work.

First its better to have class representing one item of the array, Like `Pan`

```
public static class Pan
{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String panCode;
    private String idAttachedDu;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPanCode() {
        return panCode;
    }

    public void setPanCode(String panCode) {
        this.panCode = panCode;
    }

    public String getIdAttachedDu() {
        return idAttachedDu;
    }

    public void setIdAttachedDu(String idAttachedDu) {
        this.idAttachedDu = idAttachedDu;
    }
}
```

add jackson or gson to deserialize json into this type of object (here jackson is used)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Finally get the response, convert it to array of `Pan`s then assert. (please change url as required, extra tip: use [mockoon](https://mockoon.com/) for local mock server)

```
@Test
void panRestAssuredTest() {

    Response response = given().headers("Content-Type", ContentType.JSON, "Accept", ContentType.JSON).
            when().get("http://localhost:8000/restassured").
            then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response();

    List<Pan> pans = response.jsonPath().getList("$", Pan.class);

    assertThat(pans, everyItem(
            either(hasProperty("panCode", containsString("PAN")))
            .or(hasProperty("name", containsString("PAN"))))
    );
}
```

Comment: I have ever tried your proposal and it worked. But I would like to know why the syntax before doesn't

Comment: You haven't posted how you create the response. In order to `hasProperty` matcher to work, it require a object of particular type. Just response returns map in your case (hasEntry might work but I was unable to do that way) and since its a raw array `jsonPath. getList("$")` is required to properly parse the array into body.